# Simplifying a query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Alright so I want to simplify these 2 queries into possible 1 query but I dont understand how to do it..

I went over some documentation on joins but could get my head around it, what I am basically trying to do is

- Get user ID
- Use user ID to find something in another table

First query to get User ID

```
//private function getUserID
$res = $sql->query("SELECT ID FROM users WHERE username='".$username."'");
```

And this is the 2nd one I use to find out users characters

```
$res = $sql->query("SELECT * FROM user_chars WHERE ID='".$this->getUserID($username)."'");
```

Comment: But how do I add up join on this one? Thats why I have asked this question, I dont understand how to implement it on this one, I've tried many times but failed every single time

Comment: you can do it like this:
`select * from user_chars where ID=(select ID from users where username='".$username."'" limit 1)`
But this will make your server go really slow. I suggest: store USER ID in some session variable, so you don't need to get it into each request, and clear on logout - this will speed up application.

Comment: What is it that you're not understanding about how to use joins? If you edit your question to ask about that more specifically, you may get some answers with more explanation that could help you understand.

Comment: @SmallWebDev Your query will not be slower that a JOIN solution. The subquery will be executed only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [join](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx) the two tables:

```
$res = $sql->query("SELECT user_chars.* FROM user_chars 
                    INNER JOIN users ON user_chars.ID = users.ID 
                    WHERE users.username='".$username."'");
```

This query will select everything from `user_chars` if there exists a corresponding ID in `users` and the username matches.

Comment: Aha so basically

- Join table User chars 
- Check if there are any results matching USER ID and User Character ID
- We get the ID from users.username

Correct?

Comment: If the ID's exist in both tables and they match and if `user.username` is the one you want (WHERE clause), we return everything from the user_chars table.

Comment: Wow nice one, thanks for explaining it to me, works like a charm. Marking it as a correct answer